# Single sign out with WSO2 Identity Server - WS-Federation

Tags: asp.net, wso2, ws-federation, wso2-identity-server

I got single sign in working but I don't know how to configure single sign out.

Here is what I've tried so far (without any success):

[My Service provider] -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> [my issuer] -> Enable Single Logout is Checked (custom URL is not given)

What I try is to simply redirect the browser to the URL where login is configured with the following parameter:

```
https://localhost:9443/passivests?wa=wsignout1.0
```

So the login works perfectly with this URL: `https://localhost:9443/passivests`

As I understand there is nothing else I should do but WSO2IS does not remove the cookie and when I try with my other webapp it logs me in as if nothing happened.
I omitted wreply (as it is optional) so I expect that the browser is not redirected back to my application or login screen. This is the reason I try it with a different application. Also the other app is opened FIRST after logout and it still gets the claims. (I always test with a new incognito mode chrome window to avoid false negatives because of leftover cookies)

So is there anything else I should do or is it perhaps a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug. I can't find the particular class right now but the logout function called when using WS-Fed is an auto-generated //TODO stub.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sts.passive/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sts/passive/processors/SignoutRequestProcessor.java